I am comparing the result of pandas_ta and the MACD crossing in trading view. it seems they're not the same
Hi I was trying to compare the pandas ta and trading view macd crossing.
the data compare is EURJPY 15 minutes timeframe starting from September 13, 2024 23:45
in pandas_ta I just drop all NaN and check the if it cross above or below 0 for the buy and sell signal
but the crossing are different. in trading view the first signal is sell signal between 23:15 and 23:00
in pandas_ta and ta lib it's in different time and the first signal is buy signal

With the information you provided, it’s difficult to answer your question.
Could you please share your code and if possible, some screen captures so that we can better understand the issue.
